# Mysql query for select data from multiple table with comparision

Tags: mysql

I have a three tables namely profile, academic,payment and these tables having two same columns that are username and status.

my problem is how to select username from the tables where status=1 in all the tables

Comment: Have you written any queries? What have you tried?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you add your tables and what you've tried so far

Comment: Sounds like you need to `JOIN` the other tables in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM profile
  LEFT JOIN academic ON profile.username=academic.username
  LEFT JOIN payment ON profile.username=payment.username
  WHERE profile.status=1 AND academic.status=1 AND payment.status=1
```

As a note having `username` as a key is usually a bad thing, often super bad since if someone's able to change their name you need to update N other tables. You may have a circumstance where you forget to update one or more tables, then subsequently someone registers with the former name and "inherits" this data.

It's also typically very inefficient to use a string `INDEX` key when a `user_id` integer value would suffice.

Comment: Thank you bro.. it's working. here username is unique field for all it's generated by me.. and not edited by the user